# Set up global pipeline Library with plastic scm for Jenking

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, plasticscm

I currently have a hard time grasping the concept of the Global Pipeline Libraries in jenkins. I'm a groovy newbe so please be patient with me.

I'm using Plastic SCM to store the library. It is stored in a repo that acts as a central sharing point in our project. So the groovy scripts and classes are not the only things stored there. Due to this I created a sub folder to store the groovy lib. The subfolder itselve has the structure:
Groovy_Pipline_Scripte --> src

```
                   --> vars
```

I set the Name to the path the folder Groovy_Pipline_Scripte
and the default version to a Branch in plastic.
I load it implicitly and get the error messages:

[Shared_Toolbox] $ "C:\Program Files\PlasticSCM5\client\cm.exe" gwp

d:\jenkins\test_class_pipeline@libs\Shared_Toolbox\Groovy_Pipline_Scripte\Shared_Toolbox --format={1}

d:\jenkins\test_class_pipeline@libs\Shared_Toolbox\Groovy_Pipline_Scripte\Shared_Toolbox

ERROR: Library Shared_Toolbox/Groovy_Pipline_Scripte expected to contain at least one of src or vars directories
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: Loading libraries failed

Can you help me out?
Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score -1):

Seems that it must be a separate GIT repository with 'src' or 'var' in its root and you can't have it as subfolders.